# Как, используя web фреймворк tornado, передать в class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler): аргументы, в качестве параметров?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, ооп, tornado

Есть сервер-обработчик запросов:

```
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
    ...do something with request...
```

Стартуется он из другого файла, конструкцией:

```
import tornado.web
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

from logger import Logger

app_settings = dict(
        debug=True,
        )

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler)
], **app_settings)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        object = Logger()
        application.listen(8888)
        print('Server Running...')
        print('Press ctrl + c to close')
        IOLoop.instance().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Server is out')
```

Как, используя web фреймворк tornado, передать в

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
```

аргумент(object), в качестве параметра? Неужели использовать синглтон?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, синглтон не является обазятельным. Можно осуществить передачу этого объекта через `Application`. Вы создаете новый аттрибут у `Application`, которому присваиваете ваш объект, а потом в `RequestHandler` получаете доступ к вашему доступу через атрибут `RequestHandler.application.название_вашего_атрибута`.

Вот упрощенный пример:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class MyObject():

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + " " + str(self.value)


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        obj = self.application.obj
        self.write(str(obj))


def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    obj = MyObject(1000)
    app.obj = obj
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Естественно `MainHandler` можно перенести в отдельный файл.

P.S. Не применяйте слово `object` для переменных, т.к. оно является зарезервированным.

Comment: благодарю за помощь!